# Can you use ServiceStack OrmLite's CaptureSqlFilter while still executing the commands?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Using ServiceStack ORMLite https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite I want to trace certain database calls with CaptureSqlFilter or some similar technique. However when you use this filter it captures the "intended" SQL but stops the commands actually being executed. This appears to be by design.

I want to use this or a similar technique to trace the ACTUAL calls made to the DB without stopping them.

Note that I want to do this in the code, I'm using SQL Azure so can't readily use SQL Profiler etc to achieve a similar result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable a Logger with **Debug enabled** it will log the SQL to your [registered Logging Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging).

Otherwise you can also enable ServiceStack's [built-in Mini Profiler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) which will provide access to the executed SQL.